# How best to structure Excel VBA Code for maintenance, clarity and error handling

Tags: vba, excel

Let's assume that I want to run some nice VBA code that can be best broken into four nice little sequential functions.

```
Call Init()
Call FirstStep()
Call SecondStep()
Call CleanUp()
```

However, if one of the first three fails with an error or user cancellation then I want to exit tidily and run `CleanUp`.

I started with...

```
If Init() Then
    If FirstStep() Then
        If SecondStep() Then
        End If
    End If
End If
Call CleanUp
```

But that is ugly.

Next came...

```
Select Case vbCancel
    Case Init()
    Case FirstStep()
    Case SecondStep()
End Select
Call CleanUp
```

That was an improvement but I still wonder if there is a better way? I know that VBA isn't really designed to be well structured, but none the less, I'd like to try.

Answer (score 3):

@AlexK 's answer is the standard one if the failures are due to runtime errors.

But there are circumstances where we want:

1- to run a normal sequence of operations and checkings, and the logic is such that we have to stop at some place, when one of those operations tells so by returning a boolean

2- to avoid setting up the standard error handling (there are situations where we dont want that)

3- to avoid a big number of nested If's (too ugly as you said)

The `Select Case` solution answers these requirements, but here's another one that you might prefer (the intent being clearer):

```
Do
  If Not FirstStep Then Exit Do
  If Not SecondStep Then Exit Do
  If Not ThirdStep Then Exit Do
  If Not FourthStep Then Exit Do
  ' ...
Loop Until True
Cleanup
```

Answer (score 2):

Error handling is good for error handling. Make you routines Err.Raise if there is an error, then you can:

```
on error goto ERR_IN_PROCESS
    Init
    FirstStep
    SecondStep

ERR_IN_PROCESS:
    CleanUp
```

This has the advantage of dealing with runtime errors also.

If you really don't want to use error handling you can use a briefer form of your Select

```
Select Case False
    Case Init(), FirstStep(), SecondStep()
End Select

CleanUp
```

I cant see the point of a loop, instead use scope:

```
Sub Foo()
    Run
    CleanUp
End Sub

Sub Run()
    If Not Init Then Exit Sub
    If Not FirstStep Then Exit Sub
    If Not SecondStep Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I forgot to mention that I **hate** Goto. ;-) Plus, I will be handling error trapping in each function using On Error Resume Next and then testing Err.Number and trying to resolve the problems.

Comment: Well you can re-throw the error (or a custom one) after you have dealt with it locally.  `on error goto` is not the same as using `goto` in other contexts.  Just pretend it reads `try {}`.

Comment: I'll try pretending it's try {}, but it won't be easy. Shudder. I'd say that it's on a par with the Select Case statement. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for the question was not aimed at error handling. It was for clarity and good coding standards. I'm happy to include discussions of error handling in the answers, but please don't mistake it as the reason for the question. IMHO error handling should be handled locally to ensure it is not affected by code in libraries etc.

Comment: Fair enough, there are lots of other options.